# What is the speed of an air bubble in the glass?

Tags: fluid-statics, viscosity, glass

This question arises from reading the sf poem Aniara, where the trip of the spaceship is compared to the movement of an air bubble encapsulated in a bulk of glass.
How fast can such a bubble travel?

Comment: Relevant https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-fiction-glass-liquid/

Comment: That article has a few laughable lines, including that silica glass at room temperature isn’t a solid. The author is a journalist, not a scientist. The room-temperature viscosity of ordinary glass is experimentally studied [here](https://www.academia.edu/23214730/Creep_Behavior_of_Soda-Lime_Glass_in_the_100-500_K_Temperature_Range_by_Indentation_Creep_Test), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a bubble in the glass structure of an object is an unfortunate mistake by the craftsman. The glass cools, the bubble remains and it doesn't have a speed independent of the media it's entombed within. Thus the comparison is used to figuratively illustrate a meaningless journey in the cold depths of space in this existential writing.